# Render passes on view layer only work for one frame

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to do some compositing on an animation I made. I rendered the image sequence in openEXR multilayer format and brought them back to a new file for the composting.

The problem is that all the passes only work for the first frame. If I go to the second frame of the animation, all my passes disappear.

Maybe there's some confusion with the second render layer I have stored in those frames? Anyway, I would like to know how I can solve this issue and do the compositing on the whole animation.

https://blenderartists.org/t/compositing-view-layer-only-works-for-one-frame/1208784

Here's a more detailed description of the problem as well as the .blend file where I'm trying to do the compositing.

Comment: Hi! It would be better for the community to help you if you post the same images and information in Blender Artists and here. Also, put the .blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com Then the file would be up for anyone who'll find your question in the far future.

Comment: Did you check whether the other exr files eg. the second image is containing the passes you want to comp at all? Consider using Natron, Fusion or whatever to check against the compositor, otherwise please file a bug report @CryingClouds